# How to make an unfrozen dataclass instance hashable?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

When defining a dataclass with `frozen=False` (default behaviour), and then instantiating an object of this class, is there a way to make this object hashable?

#### Why do I need this?

Before Python 3.7, I used named tuples instead of dataclasses and I used to find duplicates using `set()`, but I can't use it anymore.
I don't want to use `frozen=True` on dataclasses for other reasons.

Comment: what "other reasons"? if you want hashable you pretty much always want frozen

Comment: @wim because in one context, I need the dataclass mutability to modify attributes, and in a different context, I need to compare equality between 2 lists of these objects. Maybe I could write 2 different dataclasses with the same attributes, but one frozen, and the other not?

Comment: @DavidD.: Sounds like you may be interested in [`dataclasses.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace).

Comment: Yes! I just saw [dataclasses.astuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple) that could do the trick too

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a parameter for that:

```
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Whatever:
    ...
```

You should probably use `frozen=True`, though. If you need to update attributes on a frozen dataclass instance, you can use [`dataclasses.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace) to construct a new object:

```
new_thing = dataclasses.replace(old_thing, var=new_val)
```

You can also use a mutable dataclass instance and [`dataclasses.astuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple) to get a tuple when you need something hashable. Watch out, though - `astuple` has a bunch of weird copying behavior, so you can get behavior like the following:

```
In [1]: import dataclasses

In [2]: @dataclasses.dataclass
   ...: class Foo:
   ...:     a: object
   ...:     b: object
   ...:     

In [3]: x = object()

In [4]: a = Foo(x, x)

In [5]: b = dataclasses.astuple(a)

In [6]: b[0] is b[1]
Out[6]: False

In [7]: b[0] is x
Out[7]: False

In [8]: a == a
Out[8]: True

In [9]: dataclasses.astuple(a) == dataclasses.astuple(a)
Out[9]: False
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds very interesting. I read "if your class is logically immutable but can nonetheless be mutated. This is a specialized use case and should be considered carefully." Can you elaborate about the "unsafe" character of this?

Comment: @DavidD.: Same reason any other mutable, hashable object would be unsafe: mutation breaks any sets, dicts, or other hash-based data structures the object may be in.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. May I ask you to complete your answer with comparisons to other solutions (`replace`, `astuple`) sothat I can mark your answer as accepted? Thanks again.

Comment: @DavidD.: Answer expanded.